# Userspace use Generic Netlink Library pass NLA_NESTED data to kernel error

Tags: c, netlink, userspace

How to fill NLA_NESTED data in the Userspace Generic Netlink Library data and send to the kernel? please help me

This is my code :

```
void *msg_h = genlmsg_put(msg, NL_AUTO_PORT, NL_AUTO_SEQ, m_id, 0, 0,
                          SMC_NETLINK_UPD_LOOP_TIMEO, M_GENL_FAMILY_VERSION);

if (!msg_h) {
    return -1
}

struct nlattr *attrs_time = nla_nest_start(msg, M_NLA_LOOP_TIMEO_VAL);
if (nla_put_u32(msg, SMC_NLA_LOOP_TIMEO_VAL_TX_WAIT, info->tx_wait_timeo) < 0)
    return -1;

nla_nest_end(msg, attrs_time);

rc = nl_send_auto(sk, msg);
if (rc < 0)
    return -1;

rc = nl_recvmsgs_default(sk);
if (rc < 0)
    return -1;

return 0;
```

nl_recvmsgs_default(sk): reported an error: Invalid input data or parameter.
How should I fill in NLA_ NESTED data.please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. My kernel module `genl_family` has set two parameters,
`.maxattr` and `.policy`, which do not correspond to user mode input.